# Density of a function of Gaussian and Uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In this [research paper](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/15884265/ZhangCapacityinvestigation2015.pdf) , the authors consider the distribution of $$Y=\sqrt{(X \cos \theta+\Re{\{ N \}})^{2}+(X \sin \theta+\Im\{N\})^{2}}$$ where $N \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,2\sigma^2)$ and $\Theta \sim Uniform (0,2\pi]$.

The authors state in Eqn. (6) that $Y$ follows Rician distribution when $X=A$, given by
$$p(y \mid X=A)=\frac{y}{\sigma^{2}} \exp \left(-\frac{y^{2}+A^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right) I_{0}\left(\frac{A y}{\sigma^{2}}\right),$$ for $y \geqslant 0$
, where $I_{0}(\cdot)$ is the zero-order modified Bessel function of the first kind.

This seems **wrong** to me! If $\Theta$ was a constant I agree that the above result holds. But when $\Theta \sim Uniform (0,2\pi]$, I don't see how this is true.

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Are they using $\Theta$ in the definition of $Y$ or are they using $\Theta = \theta$ (so that they consider $Y \mid \Theta$ in lieu of $Y$)?

Comment: @WilliamM. They seem to not condition on $\Theta$.  I understand that if it was conditioned on $\Theta$, the result is correct. So, then this should be wrong, right?

Comment: If $P[Y\leq y|X=a, \theta=t]=g(y,a)$ is a function that does not depend on $t$ then you can say $$P[Y\leq y|X=a] = \int P[Y\leq y|X=a, \theta=t]f_{\theta|X}(t|a)dt = g(y,a)\int f_{\theta|X}(t|a)dt = g(y,a)$$

Comment: Not really, in multivariate analysis is not uncommon to define $Y = f(X, Z)$ and then turns out $Y$ and $Z$ are independent! Have you tried finding the distribution of $Y$ then? Recall that $P(Y \in A) = E(P(Y \in A \mid \Theta)).$

Comment: @Michael So in effect, for any realization of $\Theta$,  the pdf of $Y$ is an identical Rice distribution implying that it is independent of $\Theta$. Thus, the result is correct! Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.